# Kubuntu 20.04 font used when the font is not installed

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, lts

There's something that has been really irritating me for a while after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. In certain applications, when it tries to use an unavailable font, the font that actually gets rendered has this really weird gradient effect and huge padding for the number characters, and it also makes the application behave extremely slowly.

LibreOffice using an unknown font:
[image]

SDDM Login screen:
[image]

DB Browser for SQLite:
[image]

Comment: This could have something to do with some change you made in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which font is being used for nonexistent fonts, you can execute:

```
fc-match 'nonexistent font'
```

In my case, I was using the [Twitter Color Emoji SVGinOT Font](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font). Uninstalling the `fonts-twemoji-svginot` package made everything work perfectly again.

However digging deeper, for some reason I had many other fonts for other languages installed (e.g. noto, lohit, tamal, tlwg and several others). When I removed all of these and left basically just the default fonts installed, it also fixed the problem mentioned in this post (even with `fonts-twemoji-svginot` still installed), so it shows that this package somehow conflicts with these other ones. However I was still having other font-related issues not mentioned here, so I left this package uninstalled.